# Create comments to a range of cells ftom the values of another range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create comments to a range of cells. The comments should contain the values of another range of cells.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sResult As String

If Union(Target, Range("A18")).Address = Target.Address Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sResult = "Maximal " & Target.Value

    With Range("I6")
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Text Text:=sResult
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
End Sub
```

This works for one cell. I need this for a range of cells. For example, let's say I need the values of cells A1:F20 in comments of cells A21:F40. I do not want to copy the same Sub as many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should do you the job if you replace

```
With Range("I6")
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment
        .Comment.Text Text:=sResult
    End With
```

with

```
    For Each cell In Range("A1", "F20").Cells
    Dim V As Range
    Set V = cell.Offset(20, 0)
    With cell
    .ClearComments
    If Not IsEmpty(V) Then
    .AddComment V.Value
    End If
    End With
   Next
```

This will basically ignore all empty cells.

Output:

[image]

My code:

```
Sub TEST()
 For Each cell In Range("A1", "F20").Cells
    Dim V As Range
    Set V = cell.Offset(20, 0)
    With cell
    .ClearComments
    If Not IsEmpty(V) Then
    .AddComment V.Value
    End If
    End With
   Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a runtime error '1004' on this line:

`.AddComment Cell.Offset(20, 0).Value`

I'm not sure if it's possible to put the values directly into the comments like this... thanks for helping me out here!

Comment: sorry obviously I'm just too dumb for this^^ it doesn't work though I do have the code in the right sheet, could you post your entire code? thanks man...

Comment: Do you have any empty cells in `range("A21:F40")`?

Comment: I don't have any empty cells in `range("A21:F40")`...
It still doesn't work, even if I copy your exact code
Plus I need it as a private sub since the comments should automatically change when the values in A21:F40 change!

Sorry if my questions are totally dumb^^

Comment: Do you have any merged cells?

Comment: No, no merged cells anywhere on the sheet, also tried it with a new empty sheet, doesn't work either!

Comment: Okay I got it now! The cells were filled with numbers instead of formulas!  thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: One more question:
Is it possible to refer to a range of cells on another worksheet?
F.e. show values of  "Table 1"A1:F20 in the comments of "Table2"A21:F40?
I guess in this case the `cell.offset` function wouldn't be an option anymore, right?

Comment: Yes. It is possible to refer to a range of cells on another worksheet. Use `Worksheets("Name_of_the_worksheet").Range("Your_Range_Here")`.

Comment: `Offset` is a property of the `Range` class. It means that whenever you have a valid range, the offset property will be available for use. In your case, I figured that was an offset between the range of cells that contain the comments and the range to be commented. If you're going to tell VBA to grab comments from another sheet, the logic will change because the offset property was directly linked to the `For Each` counter as it hoops from cell to cell and copies comments. You have to make an loop that advances your another sheet range values with the `For Each` accordingly.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! This is what I meant,
I will try to set up the loop!

Comment: I would advise you to store the comments range in a variant type and then loop from its content from 0 to its upper bound. Let me know if I can help you with that.

Comment: Thanks I already solved the problem by adapting the code @PommesKlaus posted before! I posted my final code as an answer to my question if you're interested! 
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

I made some adaptions to your advices, thanks a lot, this solved my problem:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)


Dim src As Range: Set src = Worksheets("maxleft").Range("C2:K11")
Dim tar As Range: Set tar = Range("I6:Q15")

    For i = 0 To tar.Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To tar.Columns.Count - 1
        Dim sResult As String
        sResult = "Maximal " & Worksheets("maxleft").Cells(src.Row + i, src.Column + j)
        With Cells(tar.Row + i, tar.Column + j)
            .ClearComments
            .AddComment
            .Comment.Text Text:=sResult
        End With
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you want to select a range of cells (e.g. "A1:A5"), then select another range of cells (e.g. "B6:B10") and the respective values of the first selected Range should be placed as comments in the secon selected Range. Is this correct?

The following code checks if 2 ranges with an equal length are selected and copies the values of the first selected range as comments to the second selected range:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)

If InStr(target.Address, ",") Then
    Dim selected_range() As String
    selected_range = Split(target.Address, ",")

    If Range(selected_range(0)).Rows.Count = Range(selected_range(1)).Rows.Count Then
        Dim src As Range: Set src = Range(selected_range(0))
        Dim tar As Range: Set tar = Range(selected_range(1))

        For i = 0 To src.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim sResult As String
            sResult = "Maximal " & Cells(src.Row + i, src.Column)
            With Cells(tar.Row + i, tar.Column)
                .ClearComments
                .AddComment
                .Comment.Text Text:=sResult
            End With
        Next i
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That's almost what I want, but I don't want to need to select the ranges of cells, I want it to happen automatically with specific ranges of cells.
F.e. always show the values of cells A1:A5 in comments of B1:B5!