# Is there a way to show cells with long comments as a tooltip when hovering over the cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with a column of cells which each contain very long comments - and I dont want to widen the width of the cells as it will be too wide and the contents will only be viewed occasionally. The contents of each cell is dynamic, being pulled in from an external data source, and so can change from time to time.

What I'd like to do is be able to hover over the cell, and then have its entire contents show up as a tooltip or comment, but disappear when not hovering over it.

(I know I could set them up as Data validation, but since the content is dynamic this wont work).

I was wondering if its possible to do this? And also, my VBA skills are quite primitive, so if someone does happen to be able to help, would you be able to tell me exactly where to insert the VBA code and how to make it "work"!

Thanks in advance, if anyone is able to help. 
Brian

Comment: You want the code to translate your contents into comments?

Comment: This answers a similar problem try modifying it to fit your needs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315709/excel-cell-values-into-comments

Comment: Yes it is possible to show the contents when `hovering` over a cell. It is not a complex code and yet it not a simple one. Let me see if I can create a small sample

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, the only item I still need to resolve is to autosize the comment window. The default autosize doesn't do a great job, so I made the sizing static. This only works if you click the cell, so I should point that out.

Add this code to the code behind of the `ThisWorkbook` object and this will work for all worksheets in a workbook. If you want this only for one sheet, add it to the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` section behind the Worksheet(s) of interest.

```
Private LastTarget As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not LastTarget Is Nothing Then
        If Not LastTarget.Comment Is Nothing Then LastTarget.Comment.Delete
    End If

    If Not Trim$(Target.Value) = vbNullString Then
        If Target.Comment Is Nothing Then
            Target.AddComment Target.Text
            Target.Comment.Visible = True
            Target.Comment.Shape.Width = 300 'Change as needed
            Target.Comment.Shape.Height = 300 'Change as needed
            Target.Comment.Shape.Fill.Transparency = 0.6 'Make the comment a little see through
        End If
    End If

    Set LastTarget = Target
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> my VBA skills are quite primitive, so if someone does happen to be able to help, would you be able to tell me exactly where to insert the VBA code and how to make it "work"!

I usually do not answer questions which lack efforts but this question is way beyond a normal question so I am going to attempt to answer it.

**It is possible to show the contents when `hovering` over a cell. When I say `hovering`, I mean `hovering` and not `Selecting` a cell.**

The link to the sample file is posted at the end of this post.

**1.** In your file, go to the VBA editor and insert a userform. Next place a label control and resize it to fill the userform as shown in the image below

[image]

**2.** Paste this code in the userform

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Const WS_CAPTION = &HC00000

Private Declare Function GetWindowLong _
Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowLong _
Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, _
ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DrawMenuBar _
Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowA _
Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Sub HideTitleBar(frm As Object)
    Dim lngWindow As Long
    Dim lFrmHdl As Long
    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, frm.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    lngWindow = lngWindow And (Not WS_CAPTION)
    Call SetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE, lngWindow)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)
End Sub

'~~> Hide Title bar and border using API    
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    HideTitleBar UserForm1
End Sub

'~~> Stop the execution of the code
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    StopLoop = True
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

What this does is that it removes the title bar and the border of the form.

**3.** Next insert a Module and paste this code there

```
Public Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" _
(lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

Public Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Public StopLoop As Boolean

Sub StartShowingCellContents()
    Dim lngCurPos As POINTAPI
    Dim rng As Range

    StopLoop = False

    Do
        '~~> Get the cursor position
        GetCursorPos lngCurPos

        '~~> This will give the cell address "under" the cursor
        Set rng = ActiveWindow.RangeFromPoint(lngCurPos.x, lngCurPos.y)

        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            If Not rng.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
                With UserForm1
                    '~~> Display cell value in the label
                    .Label1.Caption = rng.Value
                    '~~> Show the form modeless
                    .Show vbModeless
                    DoEvents
                End With
            End If
        End If

        DoEvents

        '~~> Stop the loop (invoked by clicking on the userform's label
        If StopLoop = True Then Exit Sub
    Loop
End Sub
```

**4.** And you are done. To start, run the procedure `Sub StartShowingCellContents()`. And to stop, simply click on the userform

**5.** In action. I clicked the image using a phone so that you could see the cursor on top of that cell.

[image]

**IMPORTANT:**

1. You will not be able to perform any operations like copy, paste, delete etc till the time the code is running. Stop the code, do what you want and then run the code again.
2. Feel free to customize the code to your liking.
3. Sample file can be downloaded from [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/alyyniqh9sqtvz7/Cell%20Contents%20-%20Mouse%20Hover%20.xlsm?dl=0)