# C# Excel Add-in: set a comment for a cell

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins

I'm creating an add-in for Excel. I want to check the content in a range of cells

```
Excel.Worksheet xlWb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range selection = xlWb.UsedRange;
var values = (selection.Value as Object[,]);

if ((string)values[0,0] != "test") {
    \\ here 
}
```

if there is an error in the validation of a cell, I should add a comment or another icon.

I saw it is possible to add a comment if you work with the Worksheet.

```
Excel.Worksheet oSheet = 
               (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) excelWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
oSheet.Cells[2, 3].Cells.AddComment("Selam");
```

If I want to add a comment to all selected cells, the `selection` variable has `AddComment` but it gives me an error.

```
selection.AddComment("Hello");
```

[image]

If I try to add a comment on the first cell of the `selection`, the comment appears in the first cell of the workbook.

```
var cell = selection.Cells[1,1];
cell.AddComment("Hello");
```

[image]

If I try to add a comment in a cell where there is already a comment, I have another error.

[image]

How can I add a comment, hypothetically, in every cell of a selection?

Comment: Have you tried to call select on selection before calling AddComment? selection.Select(); selection.AddComment("Hello")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create comments to a range of cells ftom the values of another range of cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315709/create-comments-to-a-range-of-cells-ftom-the-values-of-another-range-of-cells). The answer is in VBA, but regardless of the language, you are coding against the Excel Object Model API, so the steps are the same.